Fastest method to get all single cell addresses from a range
I need a very fast method to get an array or a list of all cell addresses in a range. So Suppose i have a range "A2:B4" I need an array A2, A3, A4, B2, B3, B4. Now i can do this by looping but when there are 400.000 cells it will take for ever. Is there a smarter, faster way?
I am using C# but VBA solution is also fine.
I did already tried a lot (via parallel processing, linq, etc) but sofar it's all too slow, such as:
     For Each cell In xlRange
         addressTemp += cell.address.replace("$", "") & ";"
     Next

or

      Parallel.ForEach(xlRange.Cells.Cast(Of Excel.Range)(), Sub(cell)                                                                addressTemp .Add(cell.Address.Replace("$", ""))
                                                           End Sub)
or 

addressTemp = Enumerable.Range(1, _xlRange.Cells.Count) _
    .Select(Function(i) _xlRange.Cells(i).Address(False, False))     .ToList()


Instead of cell.address.replace("$", "") try using cell.Address(False, False).

May I ask why you need all the addresses? And do you need a 1-dimensional or 2-dimensional array?

It's going to matter if the solution lives in VBA or C#. Also what dimensions of array? or is it a List etc??

Thanks for all replies: 1) using address(false,false) is indeed a good point. but it does not save the time i need. I need this in a 1 dim list (VSTO). Currently going through the below answers.

Please, test the next fast solution:
Sub testRangeCellsAddressArray()
  Dim rng As Range, arrInit, Lett As String, arr, i As Long, tm As Double
  Set rng = Range("A2:B400000")
 
  tm = Timer
  For i = 1 To rng.Columns.count
    arrInit = Evaluate("ROW(" & rng.row & ":" & rng.row + rng.rows.count - 1 & ")") '1D array 1 based
    Lett = Split(rng.cells(i).address, "$")(1) 'extract the column letter
    arrInit = TransposeArr2DTo1D(arrInit, Lett) 'transpose the 2D column number array in 1D (adding the colun letter)

    joinArrays_ arr, arrInit 'join the cummulated array with the new one
  Next i
  MsgBox "Duration = " & Format(Timer - tm, "0.00 s")
  Debug.Print UBound(arr) 'see 
  'Debug.Print Join(arr, ",") 'uncomment to see the last part of the array in Immediate Window
End Sub

Function TransposeArr2DTo1D(arrInit, l As String) As Variant 'transpose the 2D array in 1D zero based
  Dim i As Long, arr1D
  ReDim arr1D(UBound(arrInit) - 1)
  For i = LBound(arrInit) To UBound(arrInit)
    arr1D(i - 1) = l & arrInit(i, 1)
  Next i
  TransposeArr2DTo1D = arr1D
End Function

Sub joinArrays(arr, initArr)
  If IsArray(arr) Then
    Dim NoEl As Long, i As Long: NoEl = UBound(arr)
    ReDim Preserve arr(NoEl + UBound(initArr) + 1)
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(initArr)
        arr(NoEl + i + 1) = initArr(i)
    Next i
  Else
    arr = initArr
  End If
End Sub

The message shows 1.27 seconds.
Please, send some feedback after testing it. If something look not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for calarifications.

Indeed a very nice solution, I have tested it with one sheet, will test it as well with "strange" sheets :).

@MyExcelDeveloper.com Didn't you ask about the respective cells address placed in a 1D array? At least, this is what I understood looking to your question. If it would be OK to place the the cells address in in a 2D array, containing the same rows and columns as the processed range, it would be easier (and faster). One of the above functions only transposes the column 2D array in a 1D one. Anyhow, if this was not a must I could explore much compact pieces of code, also fast enough, I think... Even the existing solution cam be improved in terms of memory handling. Without ReDim Preserve.

Sorry for any confusion, but indeed I need it in a string. Since this routine is part of a bigger project I need to be careful what I change :). I do have the intension to change the calling routines as well, but that is for later. Then I can indeed improve it a lot. Tnx

@MyExcelDeveloper.com The last code line (the commented one) does exactly that...

You said you were using C#.
So in C#, this takes 0.5 seconds for half a million cells
string xlAddress = xlRange.Address;
string fString = "ADDRESS(ROW(" + xlAddress + "), COLUMN(" + xlAddress + "),4,1)";

//a 2-dimensional array of addresses
Object[,] arr;
arr = xlRange.Parent.Evaluate(fString);

In VBA:
Dim arr As Variant
arr = xlRange.Parent.Evaluate(fString)


thanks indeed a very nice find, but it also takes some time to convert the arr(,) to a string. Also I am usually afraid do use Excel function (via exaluate etc )in VSTO, had some strange experiences with that, however this was many years ago though :).

Nice, voted up for being the most compact. But it looks that OP needed to place the addresses in a 1D array. At least, this is what I understood reading the question...

My answer differs from the some of the others because I take into account the Range object having multiple areas.
Notice how the Range object returns the first Area by default.

A For Each controls loop does iterate over every cell but is not the most efficient way of getting the address.  I use Range.CountLarge to get the actual number of cells in the range and use that to size the result array.  Next I iterate over all the areas of the range and add the calculated address to the result.
Code
Credit How to convert Excel column numbers into alphabetical characters for ConvertToLetter().
Function GetEveryCellAddressToArray(Source As Range) As Variant()
    Dim Result As Variant
    ReDim Result(1 To Source.CountLarge)
    
    Dim Area As Range
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, Count As Long
    For Each Area In Source.Areas
        For r = Area.Row To Area.Rows.Count
            For c = Area.Column To Area.Columns.Count
                Count = Count + 1
                Result(Count) = ConvertToLetter(c) & r
            Next
        Next
    Next
    
    GetEveryCellAddressToArray = Result
End Function

Function ConvertToLetter(ByVal iCol As Long) As String
   Dim a As Long
   Dim b As Long
   a = iCol
   ConvertToLetter = ""
   Do While iCol > 0
      a = Int((iCol - 1) / 26)
      b = (iCol - 1) Mod 26
      ConvertToLetter = Chr(b + 65) & ConvertToLetter
      iCol = a
   Loop
End Function

Test
Sub Test()
    Dim Source As Range, Cell As Range
    Set Source = Range("A1:J10000,K1:T10000,AE1:AN10000,AY11:BH10010")
    
    Dim Result As Variant
    Dim t As Double
    t = Timer
    
    Debug.Print "Number of Cells: "; Source.CountLarge
    Result = GetEveryCellAddressToArray(Source)
    Debug.Print "Address To Array - Execution Time: "; (Timer - t) * 1000; " ms "
    
    t = Timer
    Result = GetEveryCellAddressToArray(Source)
    
    Dim StringResult As String
    StringResult = Join(Result, ";")
    
    Debug.Print "Address To Cell Delimited String  - Execution Time: "; (Timer - t) * 1000; " ms "
End Sub

C# Code
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TestRange
{
    class RangeAddressParser
    {

        public static string AdressToCellAddresses(string rangeAddress, char delimiter = ';')
        {
            List<string> list = AddressToList(rangeAddress);
            return string.Join(delimiter, list);
        }

        public static List<string> AddressToList(string rangeAddress, List<string> list = null)
        {
            if (list == null)
                list = new List<string>();

            string[] areas = rangeAddress.Split(',');

            foreach(string area in areas)
            {
                if (area.Contains(":"))
                {
                    string[] addresses = area.Split(":");
                    (int firstRow, int firstColumn) = GetCellAddressRC(addresses[0]);
                    (int lastRow, int lastColumn) = GetCellAddressRC(addresses[1]);

                    for (int r = firstRow; r <= lastRow; r++)
                        for (int c = firstColumn; c <= lastColumn; c++)
                            list.Add(RCtoA1(r, c));
                }
                else
                {
                    list.Add(area);
                }              
            }
            return list;
        }

        private static string ConvertToLetter(int column)
        {
            int a;
            int b;
            string result = "";

            while (column > 0)
            {
                a = (column - 1) / 26;
                b = (column - 1) % 26;
                result = (char)(b + 65) + result;
                column = a;
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static (int row, int column) GetCellAddressRC(string address)
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(address, @"([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)");
            if (!match.Success)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid address format");

            string columnName = match.Groups[1].Value;  
            int row = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);  

            int column = 0;
            foreach (char c in columnName)
            {
                column = column * 26 + (c - 'A' + 1);
            }

            return (row, column); 
        }
        private static string RCtoA1(int row, int column)
        {
            return ConvertToLetter(column) + row;
        }
    }
}

C# Test
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestRange
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string address = "A1:J10000,K1:T10000,AE1:AN10000,AY11:BH10010";
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            List<string> list = RangeAddressParser.AddressToList(address);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(" Cell Count: " + list.Count);
            Console.WriteLine($" AddressToList - Execution Time: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            stopwatch.Start();
            string cellAddresses = RangeAddressParser.AdressToCellAddresses(address);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($" AdressToCellAddresses - Execution Time: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
        }
    }
}

Results
C#

VBA

VBA was 16.11% faster at creating the array and 37.73% at creating the array and joining it. This could only mean one thing, I suck at C#.  Just kidding, I do suck at C# but the reason VBA out performed C# was that I was able I knew the number of cells using VBA and initialized it to hold all the data.

optimisation can be to make an array of column Letters ONCE: string[] colsArr = new string[colCount];
for (int colIndex = firstCol; colIndex <= lastCol; colIndex++) {
colsArr[colIndex-firstCol] = ConvertToLetter(colIndex);
}, then just list.Add(colsArr[c-firstCol] + r

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that you're adding characters to a string 400,000 times. Due to the way memory management works, a copy of the string is made with room for the extra characters, the data is then copied in and that new string then becomes your string going forward.
When the string only contains a few characters already, this is a quick process, but as the string lengthens, the copy process takes longer each time.
The trick is to keep your strings to a short length, and/or only perform the copy occasionally.
You can do this by building up a temporary string and when that gets to a certain length, copy it to the main string. Depending on how long you leave the temporary string before copying to the main will influence the time taken to build your output.
The below code allows you to specify a range by rows and columns (currently set to 40,000 x 10 as per your requirement), also allows you to easily tweak the section size and then outputs the timing so you can experiment.
With the right section size (around 2,000 addresses), you should be able to build this in less than a second (depending on the specs of your machine).
VBA code:
Sub test()
    
    Dim c As Range, full_area As Range, temp_string As String, main_string As String, i As Integer, section_size As Integer
    Dim range_columns As Long, range_rows As Long, t As Long
    
    range_columns = 10
    range_rows = 40000
    
    section_size = 2000
    
    t = Timer
    
    'generate a range
    Set full_area = Range("A1").Resize(range_rows, range_columns)
    
    'start loop
    For Each c In full_area.Cells
        temp_string = temp_string & c.Address(False, False) & ";"
        i = i + 1
        If i = section_size Then
            main_string = main_string & temp_string
            temp_string = ""
            i = 0
        End If
    Next
    
    'add final part
    main_string = main_string & temp_string
    'output stats
    Debug.Print "Secs: " & Timer - t, "String length: " & Len(main_string), "Section size: " & section_size, "Cell count: " & full_area.Cells.Count
    
End Sub

Outputs:
Secs: 3.537109375           String length: 2688940      Section size: 30000         Cell count: 400000
Secs: 2.162109375           String length: 2688940      Section size: 20000         Cell count: 400000
Secs: 1.6171875             String length: 2688940      Section size: 10000         Cell count: 400000
Secs: 0.86328125            String length: 2688940      Section size: 5000          Cell count: 400000
Secs: 0.806640625           String length: 2688940      Section size: 2000          Cell count: 400000
Secs: 0.88671875            String length: 2688940      Section size: 1000          Cell count: 400000
Secs: 1.017578125           String length: 2688940      Section size: 500           Cell count: 400000


The code:
Sub CellAddresses()
    Dim A, i As Long, j As Long, t As Double
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Set InputRng = Range("A2:B400000")
    A = InputRng.Value
    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To UBound(A)
        For j = 1 To UBound(A, 2)
            A(i, j) = InputRng(i, j).Address(False, False)
    Next j, i
    MsgBox "Duration = " & Format(Timer - t, "0.00 s")
    t = Timer
    InputRng.Value = A
    MsgBox "Duration = " & Format(Timer - t, "0.00 s")
End Sub

Each of the 2 parts takes me about 2.5 seconds.

The C# code below is for both to output to a string list or to write the output to a file directly:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
static class Program {
    static char[] GetColHdr(int i) {
        if (i < 27) return new char[] { (char)(64 + i) };
        else if (i < 703) return new char[] { (char)(64 + (i - 1) / 26), (char)(65 + (i - 1) % 26) };
        else return new char[] {
                        (char)(65 + (i - 703) / 676),
                        (char)(65 + ((i - 703) % 676) / 26),
                        (char)(65 + (i - 703) % 26)
                    };
    }
    static List<string> ListOuput(int firstCol, int numOfCols, int firstRow, int numOfRows) {
        var t = new List<string>();
        var ch = Enumerable.Range(firstCol, numOfCols).Select(s => new String(GetColHdr(s))).ToArray();
        for (int i = firstRow; i <= numOfRows; i++) t.AddRange(ch.Select(c => c + i));
        return t;
    }
    static void Main() {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch(); stopwatch.Restart();
        ListOuput(3, 2000, 1, 200);
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
    }
    static void FileOuput(int firstCol, int numOfCols, int firstRow, int numOfRows) {
        var t = new StreamWriter("res.txt");
        var ch = Enumerable.Range(firstCol, numOfCols).Select(s => new String(GetColHdr(s))).ToArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
            (GetColHdr(firstCol + numOfCols - 1).Length + (firstRow + numOfRows - 1).ToString().Length + 1) * numOfCols);
        for (int i = firstRow; i <= numOfRows; i++) {
            sb.Clear();
            Array.ForEach(ch, s => sb.Append(s + i + " "));
            t.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
        t.Close();
    }
}


The fastest VBA solution (0.07 vs 0.99 s of @MGonet):
Option Explicit

Function GetColHdr(i As Long) As String
    If i < 27 Then
      GetColHdr = Chr(64 + i)
    ElseIf i < 703 Then
      GetColHdr = Chr(64 + (i - 1) \ 26) & Chr(65 + (i - 1) Mod 26)
    Else
      GetColHdr = Chr(65 + (i - 703) \ 676) & Chr(65 + ((i - 703) Mod 676) \ 26) & Chr(65 + (i - 703) Mod 26)
    End If
End Function

Sub GetCellAddresses()
    Dim B, InputRng As Range, t
    Dim j As Long, fr As Long, fc As Long, nc As Long, nr As Long
    Set InputRng = Range("$C$3:$BXZ$202")
    t = Timer
    nc = InputRng.Columns.Count: nr = InputRng.Rows.Count
    ReDim B(1 To nc)
    fr = InputRng.Row: fc = InputRng.Column - 1
    For j = 1 To nc
        B(j) = GetColHdr(j + fc)
    Next j
    [B1].Resize(ColumnSize:=nc) = B
    [A2].Formula2 = "=SEQUENCE(" & nr & ",1," & fr & ")"
    [B2].Formula2R1C1 = "=R[-1]C:R[-1]C[" & nc - 1 & "]&RC[-1]:R[" & nr - 1 & "]C[-1]"
    MsgBox "Duration = " & Format(Timer - t, "0.00 s")
End Sub

The main idea is to don't ask for the address since it's possible to generate it for the solid range. Also, the calculations are performed by Excel itself, which is significantly speeds up them.
You can save the result to a text file:

Open Notepad (or other text editor).
In Excel, click on B2, then press Ctrl+'Down Arrow', Ctrl+'Right Arrow', Ctrl+C.
Paste into the text editor.


You can find the solution for VSTO here with pure c# code, no Excel using.

Thanks all for the intersting options. For now I ended up with the following:
      For col = startCol To endCol
      collet = GetColumnLetter(col)
      For row = startRow To endRow
          sb.Append(collet & row & delimiter)
      Next
  Next
  Return returnValue

this took about ,055 sec for 450k. For me this is sufficient for now and also an big improvement. I am also always trying to keep code concise and clear. I did check most of the above suggestions and I will check the rest as well later on.
Thanks again for all input

Hey you should accept one of the other guys' answers - whichever guided you to your solution. Also as commented to @TinMan, you can optimise by loading the column letter into an array once to avoid function calls later
